# Multiple CSS class values

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create some CSS that will allow me to make my own progress bar.

The HTML5 feature `<progress value="10" max="100"></progress>` would work, but I want to do this myself.

My CSS defines the `.progressbar` to be 10px wide and 10px high (I should really rename that to `.progressPiece`, but that can come later).

```
.progressbar>div {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
}
```

For each section of my completed progressbar, I have created a class that defines what image to use:

```
.start>div {
  background: url("/images/images/pbStart.gif") right center no-repeat;
}

.startGlow>div {
  background: url("/images/images/pbStartGlow.gif") right center no-repeat;
}

.chunk>div {
  background: url("/images/images/pbChunk.gif") right center no-repeat;
}

.motion>div {
  background: url("/images/images/pbMotion.gif") right center no-repeat;
}

.end>div {
  background: url("/images/images/pbEnd.gif") right center no-repeat;
}

.endGlow>div {
  background: url("/images/images/pbEndGlow.gif") right center no-repeat;
}
```

From looking at examples, I would think the following code segments would work:

```
<div class="progressbar startGlow"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar end"></div>
```

[image: startGlow][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: end]

```
<div class="progressbar start"></div>
<div class="progressbar motion"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar end"></div>
```

[image: start][image: motion][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: end]

```
<div class="progressbar start"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar motion"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar end"></div>
```

[image: start][image: chunk][image: motion][image: chunk][image: end]

```
<div class="progressbar start"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar motion"></div>
<div class="progressbar end"></div>
```

[image: start][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: motion][image: end]

```
<div class="progressbar start"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar chunk"></div>
<div class="progressbar endGlow"></div>
```

[image: start][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: endGlow]

Obviously, my text is not producing the output I want.

All I see are non-existent boxes, as shown in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/mR2uS/).

Why doesn't this work?

**UPDATE:** Though this is now solved, I am using this workspace to develop this same progress bar using smaller jpeg images.

[image: startGlow][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: end]

[image: start][image: motion][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: end]

[image: start][image: chunk][image: motion][image: chunk][image: end]

[image: start][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: motion][image: end]

[image: start][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: chunk][image: endGlow]

Comment: All of your css selectors need '>div' removed

Comment: Got it. The overall website is large. How can I make sure these css properties are narrowed down by limiting them to div tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you're using the direct descendant operator `>` but all your divs are empty. Remove every `>div` in your CSS.
2. 10x10px is way too small to show your images. Increase the `width` and `height` of `.progressbar` to 100px.
3. A `div` is a block-level element, so you need to `float: left` your `.progressbar`

**Working fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/mR2uS/2/

Comment: That's beautiful! Thanks and have a great Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the parent selector ">" in your CSS, but there are no parent / child relationships in the HTML you presented.  You're also using DIVs to display images that should be shown on a single line.  They need to be changed to SPANs since DIVs are block elements.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mR2uS/3/) of what you are trying to get to

Instead of using background images, I used the img tag.  The default mark-up layout is the following:

```
<span class="progressbar startGlow">
    <img src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9NuV.gif">
</span>
```